# Creating Custom installer in visual studio that allows separate installation for Client and Server

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer

I have been planning to create a installer using the "Setup Project" included in visual studio. I want to create this in such a manner that it allows separate Client/Service installation using a single MSI file.
Can anyone guide me the right direction/Steps to follow. 
To elaborate it a bit more the client application will be a desktop application and the server app will be windows service.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you add a RadioButtons (2) dialog to your setup from the canned list, and make the user choose one, or checkboxes if both are allowed. If it's radio buttons, there's a property BUTTON2 which will be 1 or 0 depending on which was selected. Then each file for client or server you set a condition BUTTON2=1 as appropriate.

There are some nasty gotchas. One is that a repair will go through reinstall and the value of BUTTON2 will be undefined so you'll get unexpected results. One way to deal with this is to create a registry item with the value [BUTTON2] so that the value is saved in the registry, then you can add a search for that value to re-initialize it in case of repair.

VS setups don't have a good way of doing this because they don't have multiple features that you can choose from, and that can be modified by going into Programs&Features and changing them. VS setups all have a single feature, so all you can do is condition the files/components being installed based on checkboxes and radio buttons.

The properties window of every file being installed (Solution Explorer pane) includes a Condition property.  Selecting the file in Solution Explorer then doing F4 shows the properties window.

Comment: Which primary output will be installed. Let say i have a primary output from Desktop App and another primary output i.e a windows service so which will be installed when the user selects a radio button making BUTTON2 property = 1.

Comment: I never bother with primary output - just drag and drop the files from the builds into the Application Folder on in the Fiile view in the setup project. Then you can add the conditions on the files.

Comment: @PhilDW: I didn't get that condition the files or components. Can you please detail how to do that this step which I am looking exactly for the same operation. How to add conditions on the files?